# jQuery & Ajax: ReferenceError: ajax is not defined

Tags: ajax, jquery, reference

I get a

> ReferenceError: ajax is not defined

error in browser console when I try to make an ajax call.

I'm pretty sure I properly loaded the jQuery library, therefore I don't understand how can the $.ajax function not be defined.

Here is the HTML (without irrelevent css and markup):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a class="getUsersA">Get users</a>
            <div id="gridD"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the script.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".getUsersA").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:ajax/getUsers.php,
                type:POST,
                data:({
                    id:0
                }),
                success:function(results) {
                    $("#gridD").html(results);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you have some syntax errors.... hopefully those are not there in the actual file like `'ajax/getUsers.php'` and `'POST'`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.


Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap `ajax/getUsers.php,` in quotes. or else it would look for a local variable `ajax` rather than treating it as a string.

```
url: "ajax/getUsers.php",
```

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/getUsers.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data:({
        id: 0
    }),
    success:function(results) {
        $("#gridD").html(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything works now! I also had to wrap POST in quotes

Comment: Exactly. I showed that in the full blown example. Do mark the answer as accepted if this was useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error on this line:

```
url:ajax/getUsers.php,
```

Change this to:

```
url:"ajax/getUsers.php",
```

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to be passing a string (or a variable containing a string) as the `url` option, but you're instead doing:

```
url:ajax/getUsers.php,
```

Change it to:

```
url:'ajax/getUsers.php',
```

What you have right now is looking for the variable `ajax` (which doesn't exist) then trying to divide it by the `php` property of the object referenced by `getUsers` (which also doesn't exist), and then set the result as the value for the `url` option.